# QueryBuilders rangeQuery with null date or values

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregation

trying to found a solution for range query
using QueryBuilders.rangeQuery

Problem:
DateFrom can be null or higher than today
DateTill can be null or smaller than today
quantyti remaining can be null or value can be higher than 0

only then documents must appear in search results i was trying to solve this problem with

```
         publishedFilter.should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery(SearchAble.QUANTITY_REMAINING)))
            .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(SearchAble.QUANTITY_REMAINING).gte(1))
            .minimumShouldMatch(1);

        publishedFilter.should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery(SearchAble.DATE_TIME_FROM))
            .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(SearchAble.DATE_TIME_FROM).lte(time))
        );

        publishedFilter.should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery(SearchAble.DATE_TIME_TILL))
            .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(SearchAble.DATE_TIME_TILL).gte(time))
        );
```

but this solution working only for quantyti remaining instead of the dateFrom and dateTill

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this was an idea but this case it was not accept by requirements because 
if I had a object call him `searchDto` must be data searchable in scenarios

```
 searchDto.setQuantityRemaining(0);

 searchDto.setQuantityRemaining(1);
        searchDto.setDateTimeRange(DateTimeRangeDto.builder()
            .dateTimeFrom(null)
            .dateTimeTill(null)
            .build());

        searchDto.setQuantityRemaining(null);
        searchDto.setDateTimeRange(DateTimeRangeDto.builder()
            .dateTimeFrom(null)
            .dateTimeTill(null)
            .build());

        searchDto.setQuantityRemaining(null);
        searchDto.setDateTimeRange(DateTimeRangeDto.builder()
            .dateTimeFrom(OffsetDateTime.now())
            .dateTimeTill(null)
            .build());

        searchDto.setQuantityRemaining(2);
        searchDto.setDateTimeRange(DateTimeRangeDto.builder()
            .dateTimeFrom(OffsetDateTime.now())
            .dateTimeTill(OffsetDateTime.now().plusHours(1))
            .build());



        // and not searchable

        searchDto.setQuantityRemaining(0);
        searchDto.setDateTimeRange(DateTimeRangeDto.builder()
            .dateTimeFrom(OffsetDateTime.now().plusHours(1))
            .dateTimeTill(OffsetDateTime.now())
            .build());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way instead:

```
    // at least one of the OR conditions must match
    publishedFilter.minimumShouldMatch(1);

    // OR condition for Quantity
    publishedFilter.should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery(SearchAble.QUANTITY_REMAINING)))
        .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(SearchAble.QUANTITY_REMAINING).gte(1))
    );

    // OR condition for Date From
    publishedFilter.should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery(SearchAble.DATE_TIME_FROM)))
        .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(SearchAble.DATE_TIME_FROM).lte(time))
    );

    // OR condition for Date Till
    publishedFilter.should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .should(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().mustNot(QueryBuilders.existsQuery(SearchAble. DATE_TIME_TILL)))
        .should(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(SearchAble. DATE_TIME_TILL).gte(time))
    );
```